# How to use CodedUI for automation of an angular or reactjs application?

Tags: angular, reactjs, automation, coded-ui-tests

Require a low maintenance automation framework which can support Angular as well as react application. Please suggest any record and play framework the same. Also need to know if CodedUI supports angular applications or not?
CodedUI in enterprise edition is disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Testing tools don't care about what framework was used to develop a webpage, they only interact with the gui.
"Low maintenance" and "Record and play" don't go well together. [This](https://techbeacon.com/app-dev-testing/record-playback-test-automation-harmful) is why.

If you're only looking for good results in short term, record and play is fine.
If your looking for good results on the long term, coding test scripts should result in less maintenance than record and play scripts, if done well.

About your query for what software to use, I'd like to refer to the SO policy about asking [on-topic questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). See number 4 about why this question is off-topic.